# What does sass skip the tokenization process step while parsing mean?

Tags: css, node.js, sass, node-sass

In the sass documentation, it says "A Sass stylesheet is parsed from a sequence of Unicode code points. It’s parsed directly, without first being converted to a token stream."

What does this statement mean? If no lexing (tokenization), how does the parser know what statement is what?

I have read the documentation of sass from the following link https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/parsing/.